# Passed variable is incorrect

Tags: bash

I wish to pass a variable `patientid` from a mother script to a sub-script. The variable should correspond to the names of the folders (one at a time) in the pertinent directory.

The mother script appears as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
set verbose

# (1) have folder that contains individual patient ID folders
# (2) do for loop at at beginning of script:

counter=0

for folder in /Directory/*
do

    cd $folder

    #Obtain Patient ID as variable

    patientid=`basename $folder`

    #Pass "patientid" variable to each script you are running

    /Directory/subscript.sh $patientid    

done
```

Then, in the subscript, the variable is passed as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
set verbose

patientid=$1

cd /Directory/$patientid

###etc.
```

The problem is, in the output, `patientid` comes out as `verbose` (i.e. the directory that is used is `/Directory/verbose` when it should contain the name of the folder from that original directory). Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: I know the main issue was already solved however, the `counter=0` in your script appears unused, what is it being used for?  You should also check your code through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) and make appropriate changes it recommends.

Comment: @user3439894 thanks for the comment. `counter = 0` is used later for a progress indicator that I did not include in this script. ShellCheck looks like a good tool. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set verbose
```

Either delete this line or change it to:

```
set -o verbose
```

When you write `set verbose` that changes `$1` to the string `verbose`, which explains why `$patientid` ends up set to `verbose`.

Comment: do I change this line in the mother script, subscript, or both?